# "Expecting expression" exception thrown when declaring a default element namespace in XQuery

Tags: xml, namespaces, xquery, basex

I want to query an XML document containing namespaces, and define a default element namespace. I am using following code in BaseX:

```
session.execute("open vagelisdb");
session.execute("xquery declare default element namespace  \"http://www.satisfactory-project.eu/XMLSchema/v1.0/common\";"); 
String all_xmls_string=session.execute("xquery collection('vagelisdb')/SensorInfo/Position[x>5]");
```

But I receive the error message

> [XPST0003] Expecting expression.

in the execution of declaration. An example of the XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><SensorInfo xmlns="http://www.satisfactory-project.eu/XMLSchema/v1.0/common">
<ID>sensor_1</ID>
<Type>DepthCamera</Type>
<Position>
    <x>10</x>
    <y>12</y>
    <z>20</z>
    <Unit>Meters</Unit>
</Position>
<Space>Edw</Space>
</SensorInfo>
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare the namespace for each individual query. As is, you're sending a query with only the query prolog, but not an actual expression in line 2. Combine both to a single query.

```
session.execute("open vagelisdb");
String all_xmls_string=session.execute("xquery declare default element namespace  \"http://www.satisfactory-project.eu/XMLSchema/v1.0/common\"; collection('vagelisdb')/SensorInfo/Position[x>5]");
```

Additional hint: XQuery also allows single quotes `'` for escaping strings, so you could omit the backslashes.

Comment: Thank you for your help!That was  the solution!
Another question if you could help is if I can via xquery filtering get the whole xml file and not only the nodes that correspond to the filtering(/SensorInfo/Position[x>5])

Comment: Please ask a new question instead. The Stack Overflow model does not fit unrelated follow-up questions very well.